# Use SQL Variables in SSIS Execute SQL Task?

Tags: ssis

I am a SSIS novice and I am creating a package to run some data processing, but only if the nightly processing in our source system is completed. There is a table in the source system that contains a row for each day/time the processing occurs containing a column that denotes whether the processing is complete. I intend to use an Execute SQL Task object in SSIS to run a SQL script to query the table and return a value that indicates whether the processing is complete in order to determine if the package should proceed with execution. However, SSIS is erroring out with a syntax error whenever I execute the task. The SQL query works correctly in SSMS, so I'm sure it's something I'm missing with how SSIS operates with respect to SQL queries in the Execute SQL Task. Details are as follows:

**Result Set:** Single Row
**Result Name:** processingFinishedFromQuery
**VariableName:** User::processingFinishedFlag
**SQLSourceType:** DirectInput
**Query:**

```
DECLARE @dcdate VARCHAR(8);
DECLARE @dayruns INT;
DECLARE @tdayrunscomplete INT;
DECLARE @processingFinished BIT;

SET @dcdate = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), REPLACE(CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS VARCHAR(12)), '-', '')));
SET @dayruns = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.nightlyProcessingLog WHERE RUN_DATE = @dcdate);

IF @dayruns > 0
BEGIN
    SET @tdayrunscomplete = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.nightlyProcessingLog WHERE RUN_DATE = @dcdate AND COMPLETE = 'Y');

    IF @tdayrunscomplete < @dayruns
        SET @processingFinished = 0;
    ELSE
        SET @processingFinished = 1;
END

ELSE
    SET @processingFinished = 0;

SELECT @processingFinished AS processingFinishedFlag;
```

The error I receive is:

```
Error: 0xC002F210 at Check nighlyProcessingLog for completion, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "DECLARE @dcdate VARCHAR(8);
DECLARE @dayruns INT;
..." failed with the following error: " Unrecognized Command 
<< Syntax Error >>  DECLARE @dcdate VARCHAR ( 8 ) 
". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

Is there a way to fix this query to allow this to run as-is within the Execute SQL Task (and if so, what am I missing that would make it work) or do I have to create a stored procedure that contains a similar query and returns the value I will store in User::processingFinishedFlag?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

-Tom

PS - I tried some searching in already posted/solved questions and didn't see anything that quite matched up with this situation, so I apologize if this is a duplicate.

Update: I tried simply substituting the SQL variables for the queries that define them and used that in the Execute SQL Task. It completed without error.

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.nightlyProcessingLog WHERE RUN_DATE = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), REPLACE(CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS VARCHAR(12)), '-', '')))) > 0
BEGIN

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.nightlyProcessingLog WHERE RUN_DATE = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), REPLACE(CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS VARCHAR(12)), '-', ''))) AND COMPLETE = 'Y') < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.nightlyProcessingLog WHERE RUN_DATE = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), REPLACE(CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS VARCHAR(12)), '-', ''))))
        SELECT 0;
    ELSE
        SELECT 1;
END

ELSE
    SELECT 0;
```

It's nasty looking, but it appears to work in the SSIS Execute SQL Task as testing the query in SSMS yields the expected results and executing this task in SSIS completes successfully with the variable receiving the expected value. Is this an indication that SQL variables and/or DECLARE statements cannot be used in Execute SQL Task elements?

Comment: Good detail, much appreciated. How do you have the Results tab set up?

Comment: The error seems off to me relative to what I'm seeing in the query. If you replaced the entire query with `SELECT CAST(1 as bit) AS processingFinishedFlag;` does it work?

Comment: @billinkc '''SELECT CAST(1 AS BIT) AS processingFinishedFlagFromQuery;''' does not throw an error. As far as the results tab, I assume you mean the Result Set window where I have the Result Name set to processingFinishedFlagFromQuery and the Variable Name set to User::processingFinishedFlag?

Comment: If you're using an OLE DB connection manager, the result set name becomes the 0 based ordinal. ODBC is 1 based ordinal and ADO.NET is... named I think. The fact that a simplified version of your query works though indicates you have the result sets piece working fine... Any chance there's more to the query than you showed? I assume the target of the Execute SQL Task is a SQL Server of some variant?

Comment: Yes, I am using an OLE DB connection manager and the query I posted above is the entirety of the query I'm trying to execute in the Execute SQL Task. I originally had the results set name as 0, but changed it based on another SO post I found where the last SELECT in the Execute SQL Task was set "AS <result set name>". Interestingly, I tried simply doing a substitution to eliminate the use of SQL variables (see edit in OP) and when using that query in the Execute SQL Task, it did not error! So is it possible that the Execute SQL Task does not like/allow DECLARE statements and/or SQL variables?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried removing the semicolons from the SQLStatement?

Comment: I had not tried removing the semicolons previously. I just edited the statement and tested it and received the same error.